# Git remote operations inside Visual Studio 2013 result in the error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, git-remote

I am using Git inside Visual Studio 2013.  When I attempt to do any operation against a remote like fetch, pull, push, etc. I get the following error:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
>   A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated

I was unable to find an answer but eventually found two work-arounds.  I will post the work-arounds here.

1. I downloaded Git so I could use it outside of Visual Studio.  If I
   ran git remote commands on the command line they worked just fine so
   the problem was not with git or my remote git repository.
2. Whenever I do a remote git operation through Visual Studio it uses
   the standard windows dialog to capture the password.  I noticed that
   I would always get the error if the "Remember my credentials" box
   was checked.  If I unchecked it, it would work fine.

[image]

Comment: You found the best solution. Use git directly and skip the Visual Studio extension which is not so good.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in Visual Studio with regard to storing your credentials.  I always prefer the Git command line for basic workflow operations (merge, rebase) and rely on a plugin only when I want a visual.

Comment: Try opening the Windows Credential Manager and look up the repository. Delete the stale account details.

Comment: There is nothing saved in the Windows Credential Manager

Comment: Nice find.  Unchecking the _Remember my credentials_ checkbox fixes the problem for me.  Thanks for saving me a few hours of searching.

Answer (score 6):

Unchecked "Remember My Credentials" checkbox.

Visual Stdio 2015 asked me enter credentials **two** times.

please uncheck above mentioned checkbox both the times. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue as well on VS 2015.

- Make sure that your repository location is correct in your Global Settings (this also would probably apply to Repository Settings, if you're in a situation where you're switching credentials).
- Your Windows Credential Manager may have stale credentials. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974282/visual-studio-2013-tools-for-git-not-connecting-to-private-github-repository) to resolve that issue.