# An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error). Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: git, bash, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2013 team explorer with GitHub. I can clone and pull but can't sync and push. When I sync this error comes:

```
"An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."
```

When I tried to push from Git bash its says:

```
"remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/example.git/' not found"
```

I have gone through many answers on StackOverflow but could not solve it.

I tried deleting GitHub credentials from credential manager in control panel but it did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the remote repository to push into?

Do a `git remote add origin git@github.com:account-name/repo-name.git`.

Or `git remote rm origin` first and add it again.

Else, try including your username and password in the url like so:

```
https://username:password@github.com/repo-name
```

This seems to have solved the issue for a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974282/visual-studio-2013-tools-for-git-not-connecting-to-private-github-repository).

Also, make sure you have write access to the repository - this could also throw the error.